# Google Analytics: Greater number of pageviews from entrance source than content details

Tags: google-analytics

Looking at the Content Detail for a single page in Google Analytics (e.g. /blog), it's reporting that the page has had 94 Pageviews and 86 Unique Views.

When I look at the page entrance sources it shows 136 pageviews and 121 unique pageviews from 4 different domains.

Why is the number of pageviews reported in the Entrances Sources larger than the number in the Content Detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Entrance Sources report is showing you the number of Pageviews generated by each source for all visits that started on that page.

e.g, if you received an entrance from abc.com to your landing page and the visitor then viewed 5 more pages on your site, the pageviews for abc.com would be 6 (1 for the original entrance and 1 more for each subsequent page viewed).